# Drawing a ball of particular color at the i'th turn from an urn

Tags: probability

I've an urn with $r$ red and $w$ white balls. I'm randomly drawing a ball from the urn each round(without replacement). I'm asked the probability of the event $R_i$:Drawing a red ball from the urn in i'th turn.

$R_1$ is simply $\frac{r}{r+w}$.
$R_2$ can be calculated as follows: $$ P(R_2) = P(R2|R1)P(R1) + P(R2|R1^c)P(R1^c) $$
$$=\frac{r-1}{r+w-1}\cdot\frac{r}{r+w} + \frac{r}{r+w-1}\cdot\frac{w}{r+w}  $$ 
Since we're dealing with conditional probability, the formula for the $i$'th turn would be very messy as far as I can see. I feel there's a simple answer to this question but I'm missing the intuition. So, how should I approach to this problem?

Further, I'm asked $P(R_5|R_3)$. Calculating this also seems very cumbersome. Is there an easy way for it too ?

Comment: Maybe this is one of those situations in which the simple strategy is to calculate the probability of the event *not* happening, and then subtract that from 1, but I haven't thought it through.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Fixed that mistake and clarified the question.

Comment: That was quick.  I was able to delete the now-irrelevant parts of my comment.  Hmm: The $i$th probability is a summation of products.  It seems as if you are on the way to defining what goes after the big-$\Pi$ product sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore all the balls you don't look at.  $P(R_2)$ is $\frac r{r+w}$ if you don't look at the first ball.  The expression you have will simplify to this. 
 Imagine drawing two balls, then just before you look at the second one you switch them.  Similarly, when asked for $P(R_5|R_3)$ you can ignore the first, second, and fourth draws.  You are told the third ball is red, so when you draw the fifth you have $r-1$ red balls and $w$ white balls, giving a probability of $\frac {r-1}{w+r-1}$

Comment: Thank you. Interesting explanation. How would it work other way around ?  So for $P(R_3|R_5)$, I can think of drawing 5 balls without looking until I draw the 5th ball. If it turns out to be red, can I still conclude $P(R_3|R_5) = (r-1)/(w+r-1)$ ? And if it turns out to be white, can I conclude $P(R_3|R_5^c) = r/(w+r-1)$ ? It seems to me a bit harder to grab the intuition from that side.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.